# Imagick extension with relative paths

Tags: php, imagick

I have done much Image processing development in localhost using Imagick extension.
Now while going live, my requirement is to load images from remote url in imagick.

As per my surfing, Imagick doesn't allow images from relative paths. I can't copy files from real url to my server each time that is the problem.

Is there any way, to work with Imagick using real path?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should show what you're trying to do through code, rather than trying to describe it in words. Also - what is stopping you from just using absolute paths?